# getting the error "The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous"?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, rasterio

I am trying to plot a raster image using Rasterio, Matplotlib, and Numpy. Although what I am doing is probably irrelevant and general to the actual python code and error.

Here is the code:

```
import rasterio
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

band5 = rasterio.open(r"C:\Users\new\Desktop\LC08_L1TP_015033_20170822_20170912_01_T1_B5.TIF")

band4 = rasterio.open(r"LC08_L1TP_015033_20170822_20170912_01_T1_B4.TIF")

#rasterio.windows.Window(col_off, row_off, width, height)
window = rasterio.windows.Window(1024, 1024, 1280, 2560)

with rasterio.open(band5) as src:
    subset = src.read(1, window=window)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,8.5))
plt.imshow(subset)
plt.colorbar(shrink=0.5)
plt.title(f'Band 5 Subset\n{window}')
plt.xlabel('Column #')
plt.ylabel('Row #')
```

Complete error message with traceback:

```
runfile('C:/Users/new/Desktop/RasterSubsetNDVI.py', wdir='C:/Users/new/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-131-5d04fa0ce75f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/new/Desktop/RasterSubsetNDVI.py', wdir='C:/Users/new/Desktop')

  File "C:\Users\new\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 668, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\new\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/new/Desktop/RasterSubsetNDVI.py", line 12, in <module>
    with rasterio.open(band5) as src:

  File "C:\Users\new\Miniconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)

  File "C:\Users\new\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 177, in fp_reader
    memfile = MemoryFile(fp.read())

  File "C:\Users\new\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\rasterio\io.py", line 105, in __init__
    file_or_bytes=file_or_bytes, filename=filename, ext=ext)

  File "rasterio/_io.pyx", line 745, in rasterio._io.MemoryFileBase.__init__

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I am using code found here and trying to reproduce it on my machine with my own TIF files. Where it says "Pull an image subset at full resolution". LINK:
https://github.com/geohackweek/tutorial_contents/blob/ba5e9443137a9aca87cdcdcd70e9e6a237cc64ba/raster/notebooks/rasterio-landsat-aws.ipynb

I am running on the IDE Sypder and using Python 3.6

Please, any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: See [mcve] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you, I should have produced a code that everyone could run on their own machines. It was kind of hard because I don't know how to give people access to my TIF files. I thought maybe it might be something in my computation.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I am trying to produce this code with my raster TIF files. Here is the link to the GitHub code where the title states "Pull an image subset at full resolution", LINK:  https://github.com/geohackweek/tutorial_contents/blob/ba5e9443137a9aca87cdcdcd70e9e6a237cc64ba/raster/notebooks/rasterio-landsat-aws.ipynb

Comment: Whenever you report a Python error, include the *complete* error message (i.e. the complete traceback) in the question.  There is useful information in there.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Got it. I posted the complete traceback with the error message at the end.

Comment: Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a careful look at the following lines of your code (others omitted):

```
band5 = rasterio.open(r"C:\Users\new\Desktop\LC08_L1TP_015033_20170822_20170912_01_T1_B5.TIF")

# ...

with rasterio.open(band5) as src:
    # ...
```

From the [Rasterio documentation](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html):

> Rasterio’s `rasterio.open()` takes a path and returns a dataset object.

In the second line above, you're passing a dataset to `rasterio.open()` instead of a path.  Perhaps you wanted to pass the same path you used to create `band5` from?

It would have been nice if `rasterio.open()` checked the type of the argument you gave it and gave you an exception that said 'file path is not a string' or suchlike, but sadly it appears not to do this.

Comment: Thank you! @Luke Woodward yes that was it. I was calling rasterio.open twice. I am trying to create an 800x600 subset. Do you think this would be correct for that? Code: window = rasterio.windows.Window(1024, 1024, 800, 600)….Not exactly sure what the 1024, 1024, I know that the 800, 600 is essentially saying 800x600, but why would setting the col_off and col_row to 0 make everything purple? Also the original TIF image I had was just black and white but now when I plot it it's purple and blue. Why is this?

Comment: @yuen2: to be honest I don't know.  I've never used `rasterio` before.  It sounds to me like you have a separate question to ask, which isn't related to the error in your question.  If so, please ask a separate question.

Comment: Luke Wooward Thank you. I am getting an IndexError: list index out of range. This is  Geographic Information Systems problem. I posted the code for that error there. If you could take a look it would be much appreciated: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303119/using-rasterio-matplotlib-and-numpy-trying-to-calculate-and-plot-ndvi-of-a-ras